# Can't complete Totems of Hircine -- stuck with Aela as follower

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I picked up the Totems of Hircine quest, which forces you to keep Aela the Huntress as your follower throughout. I left it in my quest log for a while and did some other stuff, including curing myself of being a werewolf. Later when I went to do the Totems quest, I found I couldn't get into the Underforge (the door just doesn't show up as a usable object when I aim at it).

So now I can't complete the quest and I'm stuck with Aela as a follower (she doesn't have a dismissal dialogue option, and she cannot die). She also doesn't take orders or carry stuff and she gets in the way a lot, so I'd really like to get rid of her. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: are you on the PC by any chance?

Comment: Nope, XBox. No console commands. I'll add that to the post.

Comment: I tried using the alternative exit Skyrim<>Underforge but it seems to work only to go out. It was kinda fun stacking stuff to get up there though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [UESP wiki, 'Totems of Hircine'](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Totems_of_Hircine) article, you can only complete these quests as a werewolf.  In the bugs section it mentions that you can no longer access the Underforge once you are cured.  As much as it stinks to hear it, you probably have to reload an older save.

Comment: Unfortunately, by the time I discovered the problem I had already overwritten any saves I had from before curing myself. Oh well. I can get by with Aela.